# QGIS Processing Modeler not showing algorithms anymore

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

[image]

I use QGIS 3.4 on Linux Mint 18.1 and have happily created models once I came to know about this awesome feature.
But some days ago the algorithms disappeared.
If I right click in processing modeler I can only enable/disable visibility of Navigation.

In ~/.local/share/QGIS I tried

> grep -inr 'algorithms' .

To find a true/false toggle, but without luck. Am badly missing algorithms.

Comment: What if you right-click on the toolbar near the run icon ? Can you check the algorithm checkbox ?

Comment: @lejedi76 Thank you for commenting. As I wrote, I did that and can only check "Navigation". "Algorithms" is greyed out/disabled for checking.

Comment: Sorry, I miss that part. And the algorithm checkbox is unchecked ?

Comment: @lejedi76 Strangely it's checked. I updated the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute this code on pyqgis console and look if the algorithm dock appears. It could appear over the mainWindow.

```py
from processing.modeler.ModelerDialog import ModelerDialog
[dock.setVisible(True) for dock in ModelerDialog().findChildren(QgsDockWidget)]
```

Comment: Thank you for that idea! I modified your code as I got errors (create() not needed and dock is None). This worked for me `[dock.setVisible(True) for dock in ModelerDialog().findChildren(QgsDockWidget)]`